# tkinter - StringVar set and trace

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I seem to misunderstand how trace works for `tkinter.StringVar`.

I want to create a class that inherits from `StringVar`. One of the reasons is to have a different behavior if the value is changed "programmatically" i.e. using `StringVar.set()`, or "via interface", i.e. by user modifying a linked `tkinter.Entry`.

In general, I want something of the following sort:

```
import tkinter


class Str(tkinter.StringVar):

    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value=value)
        self.trace_add("write", self.entry_changed)

    def set(self, new_value):
        # Do things
        super().set(new_value)

    def entry_changed(self, *args):
        new_value = super().get()
        # Do things
        super().set(new_value)
```

since I was hoping that `StringVar.set` does not trigger trace - unfortunately it does. Now, I have in mind a workaround with a bool flag that would skip `entry_changed` one time after changing the value "programmatically", but then I realized I clearly don't understand something about how trace triggers.

**Q. Why does the `super().set(new_value)` in `Str.entry_changed` does not trigger trace?**
Since `super().set()` triggers trace in `Str.set`, I'd expect it to also trigger in `entry_changed`, creating an endless loop.

Below is an example. `entry_changed` additionally changes the `new_value` just to make sure that trace isn't triggered because the value remains the same:

```
import tkinter


class Str(tkinter.StringVar):

    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value=value)
        self.trace_add("write", self.entry_changed)

    def set(self, new_value):
        print("Set value")
        super().set(new_value)

    def entry_changed(self, *args):
        print("Entry changed")
        new_value = super().get()
        super().set(new_value + "_")


root = tkinter.Tk()
var = Str("0")
var.set("a")
print(var.get())
```

outputs:

```
Set value
Entry changed
a_
```

Comment: Traces are automatically disabled while a trace is being handled, because this would be an infinite recursion.  And before you get any further with this project, let me point out that your override of `.set()` ISN'T going to be called when the Var is changed by user action, such as typing into the linked Entry - that's happening entirely in the Tk environment, and doesn't touch the Python Var object at all.

Comment: Indeed, trace being disabled automatically makes sense. If you post this as an answer I'll accept as answered.

As for `.set` not being called when Entry is modified - that's exactly the idea.

Comment: Why not answer your own question? You can refer [the official documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/trace.html#M17) that says "While command is executing during a read or write trace, traces on the variable are temporarily disabled."